# When and how is type determined for constrained generic types when type is implicit?

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, implicit-conversion

When and how is the type of an object determined when using generics, specifically when the generic type is constrained to a class and the generic type is implicit?

To clarify, given the following code:

```
public class MyClass {}
public class MyClassA : MyClass {}

public static string GetMyClassTypeByGenericType<T>(T myClass)
    where T: MyClass
{
    return typeof(T).Name;
}

public static string GetMyClassTypeByObjectType<T>(T myClass)
    where T: MyClass
{
    return myClass.GetType().Name;
}

MyClassA myA = new MyClassA ();
GetMyClassTypeByGenericType(myA); // Result: "MyClassA"
GetMyClassTypeByObjectType(myA); // Result: "MyClassA"

MyClass myClass = myA;
GetMyClassTypeByGenericType(myClass); // Result: "MyClass"
GetMyClassTypeByObjectType(myClass); // Result: "MyClassA"
```

Why does the call `GetMyClassTypeByGenericType(myClass)` return the name of the base class, not the derived class? I'm guessing the call resolves to `GetMyClassTypeByGenericType<MyClass>(myClass)` implicitly based on the declared type of the variable `myClass`, not the actual type.

Basically, I would just like to know what's going on under the hood with generics concerning how type is determined.

Here is a fiddle for the code: https://dotnetfiddle.net/pCj08M

Comment: It's still determined at compile time. It's just inferring the type based on what is given to it, kind of like `var`.

Answer (score 2):

Generic type resolution is all compile time (which is why you cant stuff a `Type` variable in a generic type parameter without reflection, which isn't really what we're talking about there).

Hence, when its given a variable type `MyClassA`, that's what its going to use. Similarly for `MyClass` even if the actual object is a derived type. For example, if you held it in an `object` reference then the first call would print `System.Object`.

On the other hand `GetType` is run time, so it gets the *actual* type of the object no matter what the type of the variable holding it is.

Comment: Not to muddy the waters but you _can_ "stuff a `Type` variable in a generic type parameter" using the Reflection API ([`Type.MakeGenericType()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makegenerictype(v=vs.110).aspx)).

Comment: @TypeIA Well, yeah. Not exactly what's going on in the OP but you are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Generic type construction, the process of resolving the actual types of each generic type parameter, is always performed at compile time in C# (unless, of course, you're using the [Reflection API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makegenerictype(v=vs.110).aspx) to construct a generic type at runtime).

In your example, the compiler is inferring the type `T` based on the **static** type of the argument passed to the method. `myClass`'s static type is exactly what you declared it to be: `MyClass`. So when you examine `T` in the generic method you find that `T == typeof(MyClass)`.

On the other hand, when you call `.GetType()` on the object passed in, you're making a runtime query of the dynamic (actual runtime) type of the object, which of course is what you constructed, `MyClassA`.

Comment: "Specialization" is a C++-ism, which should probably be avoided to prevent confusion with templates (which generic types are not). .NET talks of *constructed* or *closed* generic types.